# How can I catch print(debug) from stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, sybase

We have stored procedures in Sybase DB.
We can execute them with parameter debug.
If we execute SP in this way, all is OK, parameter is 0, no debug.

```
DEBUG
{ ? = call up_tran_ps_bal '31/10/2014',1123456789,0,'DAVKA',NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL }

(1 row affected)
(return status = 0)
(1 row affected)
```

But sometimes we need execute SP with parameter debug, i.e. parameter 101.

```
DEBUG
{ ? = call up_tran_ps_bal '31/10/2014',1123456789,0,'DAVKA',NULL,NULL,NULL,101,NULL }
Debug ...
Debug ...
Debug ...
Debug ...
Debug ...
(1 row affected)
(return status = 0)
(1 row affected)
```

After execute stored procedure there is detail debug from command print.

How I catch this debug in Java and process it?

Answer (score 0):

After consultation with professional programmer this functionality is not possible in Sybase.